# my row lose his height when i use z-index as hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Hi i'm doing a hover effect in my cards using Bootstrap and z-index but the problem the i have is when i pass the mouse in my cards the z-index works fine but my row lose his height, i tried to add a height to my row and it fixed but my row lose the responsive, when i looks in other resolution it looks with a big space, i need it works with a responsive for different resolution and i need to use position: absolute; because i dont want it just push the cards I need z-index to raise the cards not to push it. thank you for read me and i hope you can help me

[here is my example](https://codepen.io/SoyLuck/pen/qBoJQGP)

i try to add a height to my row but it lose the responsive

```
.row{
  height:300px;
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  transition: 1s;
}

.card:hover {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0px;
  width: 130%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition(all .2s ease-out);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <div class="row bg-danger">
    <div class="mt-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
      <div class="card m-3" style="width: 18rem; height:20rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text">card 1</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-warning">
    <div class="mt-2 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
      <div class="card m-3  " style="width: 18rem; height:20rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-text">Card 2</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's because of `position: absolute` not `z-index` and it's expected behaviour

Comment: hi thanks for help me but if i remove position: absolute, z-index just push the card, i need to elevate the card not push what can i do ?

Comment: I don't understand where you want to elevate the card if it's fully visible.

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements - but it doesn't have to be absolute, any other value other than the default `static` also works - so `relative` should do. If you tried absolute because otherwise the content starts to jump around when you try to change the width, then replace that with a scale transformation perhaps. (Depends on what exactly you want to achieve.)

Comment: i need to push my card down to front of my second card and row, only some px without move the second row and card, or if i touch the second card my card pass front all rows and cards without move of his site  is something like a zoom

Comment: if the card is raised, the row runs out of items and therefore loses his height what i'm trying to do is if i give a height to my row my rows works with the responsive because if looks in different resolution my row continun with the same height that I gaveit

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to move your card up a bit, when it it is hovered. Just change the styles of your card on hover to this

```
.card:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    width: 130%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition(all .2s ease-out);
 }
```

Comment: if the card is raised, the row runs out of items and therefore loses his height what i'm trying to do is if i give a height to my row, my rows works with the responsive because if i looks in different resolution my row continun with the same height that I gave it and it looks with a big height

Comment: What you should do in this case is that instead providing a fixed height, provide a `min-height` to the row. You can also add some vertical margin to the card to ensure that row does not loses height.